# Google Drive Setting mime types properly in Python

Tags: python, file-upload, google-drive-api, mime-types

I'm building a command-line Python script to upload files to Google Drive.
My goal is to upload any file, regardless of the file type.

According to the documentation, when I'm uploading a file (regardless of whether I'm using a media upload or simple upload) if I leave mime_type set to None, Google Drive should automatically set the mime type accordingly. It works great for most file types. Here's a simplified example of how I upload a file:

```
def upload(service, title, parent_id, mime_type, filename):
    media_body = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
    body={
        'title': title,
        'mimeType': None
    }
    body['parents'] = [{'id': parentID}]

    try:
        service.files().insert(body=body,media_body=media_body).execute()
    except apiclient.errors.HttpError, e:
        #catch the error
```

The problem is when the file is an executable, database, or other application support file, Google drive doesn't seem to be able to handle setting the mime_type properly and throws an error: "HttpError 400 "Media type 'None' is not supported. Valid media types: [ * / *]"

I catch the 400 error, and I then try uploading the file using the mime_type "binary/octet-stream" which seems to at least let the request go through. But when the file is uploaded, it is 0 bytes in size i.e. the file is created but none of the content is uploaded.

I've also tried to set the mime_type according to Python's built-in "mimetypes.guess_type(url)" function, but even with this specificity it doesn't seem to work properly.

Can anyone help point me to how to set mime_type so that regardless of the file type, it gets uploaded correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ryan's answer below helped point me in the right direction.

But also good to note that I discovered that simple upload doesn't work for executable/source/app support files. You can only use a media upload for these types of files regardless of whether they are small...

Unfortunately this adds quite a bit of http overhead to my app, because media uploads cannot be batched... oh well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`binary/octet-stream` isn't actually a valid mimetype, I believe. Are you sure you're not looking for `application/octet-stream`?

[This Python script for Google Drive uploading](https://github.com/jbmorley/google-drive-upload/blob/master/google-drive-upload#L101) seems to use it as well.

Comment: Ah yes thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I just tried something similar to the script you linked and it worked like a charm. 

Thanks so much!